# TypeError: Cannot read property 'brewery_type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I try to send each brewery from the App.js to the Brewery.js it gives me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'brewery_type' of undefined" error on line 75 in Brewery.js. I suppose it's because nothing is sent to Brewery.js and there is no brewery found. I also tried to console.log each brewery in App.js within the iteration but it didn't seem to be working for me.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Brewery from './components/Brewery'
import DetailPage from './components/DetailPage'
import Menu from './components/Menu'
import Random from './components/Random'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import Category from './components/Category'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div>
      {this.state.breweries.slice(0, 10).map((brewery) =>
        <Brewery key={brewery.id} brewery={brewery}/>
      )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <div> <Menu /> </div>
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Brewery} exact/>
              <Route path="/brewery" component={DetailPage} exact/>
              <Route path="/random" component={Random} exact/>
              <Route path="/:brewery_type" component={Category} exact/>
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
        <div> <Footer /> </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Brewery.js

```
import React from "react";
import './Brewery.css'
import DetailPage from './DetailPage'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    }
  }

  sortAlpha() {
      const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0,10)].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
    }

  sortRevAlpha() {
    const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0,10)].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
  }

  render() {
    const { breweries } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="banner">
          <div className="banner-content">
            <h1>Brewery</h1>
            <p>Find the best brewery in town</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="brewery-sort">
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <DropdownButton
              bsStyle="default"
              title="Sort"
              noCaret
              id="dropdown-no-caret"
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={() => this.sortAlpha()}>Alphabetically (A-Z)</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={() => this.sortRevAlpha()}>Alphabetically (Z-A)</MenuItem>
              </DropdownButton>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <Link to={`/brewery`}>
                  <div className="card">
                     <div className="card-description">
                      <h2>{this.props.brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                      <p>{this.props.brewery.city}, {this.props.brewery.state}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-name"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/20/000000/beer.png" alt="beer"/>  {this.props.brewery.name}</div>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

Comment: What is the output of console.log(this.state.breweries)?

Comment: It doesn't really output anything, when I console log it it looks like it fetches 12 items from the API

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your `Brewery` component you need to change it to:

```
 <h2>{this.props.brewery.match.params.brewery_type}</h2>
```

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: can you console.log the this.props of your Brewery component please?

Comment: Nothing is logged when I do that

Comment: I believe nothing is passed from App.js because in Brewery.js brewery is not defined

Comment: You have your App component and within it you have your Brewery component where you pass props, so logging the props within your render in Brewery component should output props. You might have to check if your response has arrived. So, within render of Brewery check if the array is populated: `if (this.state.breweries === 0){
  return <div>Loading<div/>
}`

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: Also when I log this.props.brewery in Brewery.js it gives me "undefined"

Comment: have you tried to console.log this.props and not this.props.brewery? have you tried to return a Loading div until your array is populated?